# how to change the first parameter of cts:search query formed by search:search API?

Tags: indexing, marklogic

As we know at the end `search:search` will form `cts:search` query.
In the formed `cts:search` query, always the first parameter is coming as `fn:collection()`

Is there any way we can change the first parameter to `fn:doc()` or `fn:collection('some_collection')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated based on comments

You can accomplish the same result by adding a **cts:collection-query("some-collection"**) in the **'additional query'** section of the search options. This will AND it onto the query created.

In addition, you can also use powerful search options for more granular control. One example is:
`<searchable-expression>`

Furthermore, when using structured queries, you also have the power of the various search options:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_59265
One of which is a **document query** or **directory query** or **container**

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev

Comment: Yes That is what currently I am doing,

But I have to pass in the first parameter of cts:search()

Actually I have to pass fn:doc("uri")/some_path

Comment: updated based on the additional information you gave in your comment. If this is not sufficient, please expand on your question giving a more complete example.

Comment: Note that you must put the serialized version into <additional-query>: `<cts:collection-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
<cts:uri>some-collection</cts:uri>
</cts:collection-query>`. You can find the serialized version of any query like this: `<r>{cts:collection-query("some-collection")}</r>/*`.